# How to parse HTML content in dart with styles and line break?

Tags: html, flutter, dart

I want to parse the html content in dart with line breaks as in the html content. I used this [html: ^0.15.0](https://pub.dev/packages/html) package for this. but it won't return the the exact content with line breaks specified.

I want this [image]
I get this [image]

how to solve this.

Comment: Could you add your dart code?

Comment: you can use flutter_html package to use html in dart(flutter)

Answer (score 0):

Please use this package : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html

Wrap your html content from server like this.

```
Html(
     data: data.content,
     defaultTextStyle: GoogleFonts.nunito(
        color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1.color,
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        height: 1.5),
     ),
```